# How to get make Cloudformation us a Public AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ami, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

My Task is to automate the creation of an EC2 instance using CloudFormation. I have a script working perfectly with a private AMI. My query is it possible to use an AMI from the marketplace? When I use the AMI ID, when I run the script it says the ID can't be found.

```
ec22instance:
  Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
  CreationPolicy:
    ResourceSignal:
      Timeout: PT20M
      Count: 1
  Properties:
    DisableApiTermination: false
    EbsOptimized: false
    ImageId: ami-071a99b84dd2f2924
    InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior: stop
    InstanceType: m4.2xlarge
    KeyName: !Ref PemKeyName
    Monitoring: true
    SubnetId: !Ref AppAz1SubnetId
    IamInstanceProfile: !Ref InstanceProfile
```

Comment: First, have you confirmed that you can run the instance manually with the AMI using EC2 console? Using market place may require you to accept termes and conditions first.

Comment: Yes, it's been used manually before, I believe the solution is to launch the AMI and create a private AMI of it. So, more of a prerequisite it seems